# HTA, Outlook Global Address List, bring to front

Tags: vbscript, back, hta, gal

I have an HTA application that launches Outlook's Global Address List (GAL) so that the user can easily pick an email recipient from our company directory. However, when launched the GAL window is not brought to the front of the screen. It is displayed behind the HTA.

Here's my code. Is there a way to bring the GAL to the front (or move the HTA to the back)?

```
<HEAD>

<!---------------Resize & Move Window------------------------------>

<script language="vbscript"> 
window.resizeto 400, 300
screenWidth = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth
screenHeight = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight
posLeft = (screenWidth - 400) / 2
posTop = (screenHeight - 300) / 2
window.moveTo posLeft, posTop
</script>

<!---------------Application Info---------------------------------->

  <TITLE>GAL Picker</TITLE>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="MyApp" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="My GAL Picker" 
    BORDER="Dialog"
    CAPTION="Yes"
    SCROLL="no"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="Yes"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="Yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
    SYSMENU="Yes">
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<body STYLE="font:12 pt arial; color:white;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#000000', EndColorStr='#0000FF')">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

'''''''''''''''''''''SUBS''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub GALPicker
  Dim objWordApp
  Dim strEmailName

  Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  strAddress = objWordApp.GetAddress(, "<PR_DISPLAY_NAME>", False, 1, 1, , True, True)

  If strAddress = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  Else
  End If

  msgbox strAddress
  MyGal.Value = strAddress

End Sub

</SCRIPT>


<H2>My Outlook GAL Picker</H2>
<P>Add Email Recipient:
<input type="text" name="MyGAL" size="30" onfocus="vbscript:Call GALPicker">
```

Comment: Have you tried using `AppActivate`?

Comment: Yes. Today I tried using: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   wshShell.AppActivate "Select Name".  But regardless of where I place it in the code it doesn't pull the Outlook GAL to the front.  I believe this is because the code pauses for user input on this line of code: strAddress = objWordApp.GetAddress(, "<PR_DISPLAY_NAME>", False, 1, 1, , True, True).

Comment: You could call a second script from your first that uses `AppActivate`. That way, it won't be blocked by `GetAddress`. Your second script could loop until `AppActivate` returns `True` (or until some kind of timeout occurs).

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how I would modify the script to make this work? I tried calling a second script but the Outlook GAL still stalls waiting for user input before running the rest of my script.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so that the code is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of using `AppActivate` in a second script so that it doesn't block your main script.

In your main script:

```
' Call a second script (asynchronously) to activate the window...
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "activate.vbs", 0, False

' Now load our GAL window...
strAddress = objWordApp.GetAddress(...)
```

The second script (`activate.vbs`) would look like this:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Try to activate the GAL window for 10 attempts/seconds...
For i = 1 To 10
    If Shell.AppActivate("Select Name") Then Exit For
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Next
```

So we kick off the second script and then continue on with the loading of the GAL "Select  Name" window. The second script will try 10 times (waiting a second between each attempt) to see if it can find the "Select Name" window and, if it does, it will activate it.

It's a bit of a hack but it just might work!

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Bond! I see what you mean. That worked great. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here's what I ended up doing...

```
    <HEAD>

    <!---------------Resize & Move Window------------------------------>

    <script language="vbscript"> 
    window.resizeto 460,255 
    screenWidth = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth
    screenHeight = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight
    posLeft = (screenWidth - 460) / 2
    posTop = (screenHeight - 255) / 2
    window.moveTo posLeft, posTop
    </script>

    <!---------------Application Info---------------------------------->

      <TITLE>GAL Picker</TITLE>
      <HTA:APPLICATION ID="MyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="My GAL Picker" 
        BORDER="Dialog"
        CAPTION="Yes"
        SCROLL="no"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON="Yes"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON="Yes"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
        SYSMENU="Yes">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <body STYLE="font:12 pt arial; color:white;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
    (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#000000', EndColorStr='#0000FF')">

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    '''''''''''''''''''''SUBS''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

  Sub GALPicker
  Dim objWordApp
  Dim strEmailName

  Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'new line of code proviced by Bond, adjust file path as needed
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\activate.vbs", 0, False

  strAddress = objWordApp.GetAddress(, "<PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS>" & " ### " & "<PR_DISPLAY_NAME>", False, 1, 1, , True, True)
  If strAddress = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  Else
  End If

  msgbox strAddress
  MyGal.Value = strAddress
  End Sub

    </SCRIPT>

    <H2>My Outlook GAL Picker</H2>

    <P>Add Email Recipient:
    <input type="text" name="testGAL" id= "MyGALTest" size="36" onfocus="vbscript:Call GALPicker">
```

Then I created a new .vbs file per Bond's recommendation...

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    ' Try to activate the GAL window for 10 attempts/seconds...
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Shell.AppActivate("Select Name") Then Exit For
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Next
```

Comment: Looks good. I see you changed the `Sleep` time to 100ms. Just know that your script will only look for the "Select Name" window for 1 second now (100ms * 10 iterations) before giving up. If you find that your window isn't getting activated anymore, try increasing the number of iterations in this loop and/or the sleep time.